# Running ruby selenium scripts on Cronjob - Chrome

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, cron

I am trying to run a selenium ruby script on Chrome through crontab but don't see anything run.
I tried the following as suggested in other questions:

```
crontab -u shamanth -e
```

Added the following

```
MAILTO=""
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
export DISPLAY=:0 google-chrome
47 13 * * * /usr/bin/ruby ~/Desktop/script.rb
```

From the cron logs `/var/log/syslog`, I see that the script has started (I put some print messages in the beginning of the script) but I don't see chrome launching.

Permissions have been given to the script file.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem is with the path you are setting: `crontab` works in a very limited environment, where paths like `~` are not understood.

For that, instead of saying

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/ruby ~/Desktop/script.rb                # NO!
#                       ^
```

say

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/ruby /home/your_user/Desktop/script.rb  # YES!
#                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: @Shamanth "didn't work" is not enough: what is the status? what does work and what does not? Provide more details if you want to be helped.